# Why eclipse change the permission and how to disable it?

Tags: eclipse, zend-studio, samba

I work with eclipse (in fact last version of Zend Studio) and the project i currently work on is in a distant directory mounted with samba.

When i save a PHP file, permissions are changed and the executable flag is added. I don't have the problem when i execute a touch on the file.

Did you already encounters this problem? How to resolve it?

Thanks

Comment: Isn't it the samba which changes the permissions? Have you tried editing the files in some other program than Eclipse (but still using the distant directory offered by samba)?

Comment: I tried with touch and vim and the permissions didn't change. I thinks this is related to samba too, but why eclipse does that? My admin switch create permission on the shared directory and now it works. Maybe eclipse delete and re-create the file. Weird.

Comment: Maybe you can try to strace Eclipse and see what it really does?

Comment: I find something interesting there : https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=323681

Comment: That's a good finding. But they claim they have fixed the problem in 3.6. Is your Zend Studio using an older version of the Eclipse platform?

Comment: No, i think this will be ported in 3.7  and someone offers to do a backport https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=323681#c37 Zend Studio use the last stable version (august or september 2010)

Comment: You're right. I thought it's the Version field there, but it's the "Target Milestone" which is the one about when will be the things solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that it's related to a bug in eclipse : 
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=323681#c37

Meanwhile, a modification of the shared directory configuration helped to resolve the problem for some files.

Thanks.